# ¿Cómo se modifica el tamaño de una imagen medinate PHP cogiendo solo forma cuadrada?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer dos cosas a una imagen.

1)Reducir tamaño de una imagen de manera que el lado más corto (altura o anchura) sea de 400px. Por supuesto sin CSS, ya que quiero que ocupe menos la imagen.

2)Cortarlo en forma cuadrada tomando como eje superior izquierda.

Es como cuando se registra un usuario y sube la imagen de avatar y se ajusta.

Añado una imagen como ejemplo y el cuadrado con linea discontinua es el objetivo a conseguir por ejemplo con 400px X 400px como se indica en el ejemplo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Imagick

```
<?php
    $inFile = "test.jpg";
    $outFile = "test-thumbnail.jpg";
    $image = new Imagick($inFile);
    $image->thumbnailImage(400, 400);
    $image->writeImage($outFile);
?>
```

Puedes encontrar mayor información en:

http://php.net/manual/es/book.imagick.php

https://www.sitepoint.com/crop-and-resize-images-with-imagemagick/